# How to make a shiny app single page with multiple tabs

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a shiny app that change tabs when scrolling down, like this app:

https://gallery.shinyapps.io/cran-explorer/#cran-stats

Does anyone know how to make that?

Thanks.

Comment: check source code here https://github.com/nz-stefan/cran-explorer

Comment: You could probably use [Tocify](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.tocify.js/) and stylize it to be horizontal.